# Error when using exchange variables PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Well I have this PL/SQL statement:

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
ACCEPT lastname PROMPT 'Please enter a Lastname';

DECLARE
  lastn employees.last_name%TYPE;
  sal employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
 lastn := &&lastname;
  SELECT salary INTO sal FROM employees WHERE last_name = lastn;
  IF sal < 3000 THEN
    sal := sal + 500;
    UPDATE employees SET salary = sal WHERE last_name = lastn;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lastn||' salary updated');
  ELSIF sal > 3000 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lastn || ' earns ' || sal);
    END IF;
  END;
```

If I input a name f.e. 'King' I get an error message. The error message is: "Identifier 'KING' must be declared".

Comment: Not sure how you are calling the store procedure, but I think that the identifer in the call should be something like: lastname:'king' or something alike...

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider that the string `&&lastname` in your script will be replaced by the value you insert at runtime; this means that when you give 'King', your code becomes:

```
lastn = King;
```

which obviously gives an error.

What you just need is quotes:

```
lastn := '&&lastname';
```

With a script **x.sql** lke this:

```
ACCEPT lastname PROMPT 'Please enter a Lastname ';
DECLARE
  lastn varchar2(100);
BEGIN
 lastn := '&&lastname';
 dbms_output.put_line('lastn = ' || lastn);
END;
/
```

If you try to use SQL*Plus with

```
set verify on
```

you can see this behaviour:

```
SQL> @c:\temp\x
Please enter a Lastname King
old   4:  lastn := '&&lastname';
new   4:  lastn := 'King';
lastn = King

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: If I use your code I get this error: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: This probably means that you have more than one record in employee table that matches the lastName condition. You need to understand  whether you need to handle many matching records or not, and then edit your code accordingly.